# Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried: (Linux)

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, sqlite, npm

I have a discord.js bot. I found a linux host and moved the bot. I am getting this error and i have no idea why.

Node.js version       14.6.0

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) x86_64
CPU: AMD Opteron 6128 HE (10) @ 2.000GHz
GPU: VMware SVGA II Adapter

````
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Debug/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Debug/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Debug/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Release/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Release/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/default/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/compiled/14.6.0/linux/x64/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/release/install-root/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/debug/install-root/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/default/install-root/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |  → /home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/better_sqlite3.node
0|serverai  |     at bindings (/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:126:9)
0|serverai  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:9:24)
0|serverai  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1236:30)
0|serverai  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1257:10)
0|serverai  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:32)
0|serverai  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:14)
0|serverai  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:19)
0|serverai  |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
0|serverai  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
0|serverai  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/index.js:2:18) {
0|serverai  |   tries: [
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Debug/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Debug/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Debug/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Release/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Release/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/default/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/compiled/14.6.0/linux/x64/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/release/install-root/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/debug/install-root/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/default/install-root/better_sqlite3.node',
0|serverai  |     '/home/serveraisystem/server-ai-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/better_sqlite3.node'
0|serverai  |   ]
0|serverai  | }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed build-tools on that machine?  Try this from the project directory:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ rm package-lock.json

$ npm install build-tools -g
$ npm install
```